# OTC whirlpool low profile microwave

Tags: microwave-oven

I recently bought an over the range low profile whirlpool microwave. I have just a hood before.
The only stud is directly in the center, which the template to hang only has diamond like marks to center it. Instructions say to attach at one stud either on the right side or the left nothing about center. I have toggle screws too. A little info on my wall it is drywall plaster and laths.
Will the toggles be enough if I use several??
Should I try a screw in the center??

Comment: Model #? If the design is such that you can get two screws into one stud *vertically* a couple of inches apart then that will take the weight and toggles on left and right will help keep it steady. But if the design is such that multiple screws only work horizontally and not vertically then **no**, I wouldn't rely on one screw + toggles. An alternative might be if there is a way to mount from the left and right into the side cabinets, but it all depends on what the instructions allow.

Comment: Please post a picture.

Comment: Drywall *over* plaster and lath?  You could simply remove some wall and put in some blocking.  The repair doesn't need to look good since it'll be covered by the nuke.